# XML location on document function in XSL is not working in Unix/Linux server

Tags: xml, xslt, sas

I am using SAS PROC XSL to create a new XML by consolidating info from more than one XML. For this purpose am using Document() function with path to the XML file in the (). This code is working fine when I submit the code on Windows, but not on LINUX server. To my surprise there is no error or warning message in the log. I am using XSL processer 1.0.

content of xsl file used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
    <xsl:comment>One Argument </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:for-each select="document('/project/dev/xml_test/b.xml')//a">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:comment>Two Argument </xsl:comment>
    <xsl:for-each select="document('/project/dev/xml_test/a.xml', .)//a">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

SAS code:

```
filename infile "/project/dev/xml_test/b.xml" ;

filename style "/project/dev/xml_test/xslfile.xsl"; --the content is as given above

filename outfile   "/project/dev/xml_test/c.xml";



proc xsl in=infile xsl=style out=outfile;
run;
```

Comment: Please include enough information, preferably code and data, to reproduce your problem.  Also, do not use ALL CAPS in your title.  (Fixed.)  Thanks.

Comment: Here is the xml content and the xsl file used..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a URI format for your specification of the filename argument to the `document()` function:

```
file:///path/to/document.xml
```

Or, for Windows if you require a drive designator:

```
file:///x:/path/to/document.xml
```

Note that there are three `/`s in a row.  (Normally there'd be two `/`s followed by a `host` followed by another `/`, but for the local filesystem, the host is omitted.)

Comment: Hi kjhughes, The solution you gave is working fine. Thanks for the help.